# How to show this integral equality?

Tags: integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals

The given equality is

> $$b \int_0^1 \frac{x^{a-1}}{b+x^n}\,dx=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^k}{b^k(nk+a)}$$

i tried using Riemann sum but had no luck , any idea how to proceed

Comment: Any restrictions on $n$? What about $b$?

Comment: i have $\Re{\{n\}}>0,\Re{\{a\}}>0$ , and no condition on $b$

Comment: Metric on what? $a,b\in\Bbb{R},$ yes?  You should give us a little more information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try manipulating the integrand into a geometric series:

$$ \dfrac{x^{a-1}}{b+x^n} = \frac{x^{a-1}}{b}\dfrac{1}{1+x^n/b} = \frac{x^{a-1}}{b}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\left(\frac{x^n}{b}\right)^k = \frac{1}{b}\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k\frac{1}{b^k}x^{nk+a-1}  $$

Now integrate, which we can do inside the interval of convergence.

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you know what theorem justifies the interchanging of summation and integration ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the binomial theorem, which states (with some restrictions) the following:

$(a+b)^n = \sum_{k=0}^∞ a^k b^{n-k} {n \choose k}$.

So if the sum converges, your left integrand becomes

$x^{a-1} \sum_{k=0}^∞ (x^n)^k b^{-1-k} {-1 \choose k}$.

In a roundabout way, ${-1 \choose k} = {(-1)}^k$ for a nonnegative integer k.

If all is well-behaved, summation and integration commute, so your left side becomes

$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \int_0^1 x^{a-1+nk} b^{1-1-k} {(-1)}^k dx$,

which simplifies to

$\sum_{k=0}^∞ b^{-k} {(-1)}^k \int_0^1 x^{a-1+nk} dx$.

That leaves you with integrals of the form

$\int_0^1 x^{a-1+nk} dx$,

which are just integrals from zero to one over powers of x, which a small amount of calculus will convert to

$\frac{1}{a+nk}$.

And $b^{-k}$ is just $\frac{1}{b^k}$, so your sum becomes

$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{{(-1)}^k}{(b^k )(a+nk)}$.

And that's the right side. I've glossed over a bunch of ways this might go wrong (your infinite series might not converge sometimes, or b could be zero, to name a few), but I think that in any case in which you're using this identity, you probably already know about those.

Comment: This site has latex support. Please use it. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry for the mess, and I'm happy to have an easy way to clean it up.